# How does $\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$ being simply connected follow as a corollary from $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ being a strong deformation retract?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory

From *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* by Lee:

[image]

---

---

We know $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ is simply connected for $n\ge 3$.

We know that since  $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ is a strong deformation retract of $\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$, then $r \circ \iota = \mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb S^{n-1}}$ and $\iota \circ r \simeq \mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}}$, where $\iota:\mathbb S^{n-1} \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$ is inclusion.

***We do not know homotopy invariance of $\pi_1$.***

**So, how does the corollary follow from the proposition?**

Comment: If $X$ is a strong deformation retract of $Y$ then $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Right. But then how does the corollary follow? Homotopy invariance of $\pi_1$ is still not proven.

Comment: Homotopy equivalent spaces have isomorphic fundamental groups.

Comment: I've edited the post to include: We do not know homotopy invariance of $\pi_1$.

Comment: @Wojowu I've edited the post to include: We do not know homotopy invariance of $\pi_1$.

Comment: But you *do* know that $r_*\circ\iota_* = \text{id}\colon\pi_1(S^{n-1})\to\pi_1(S^{n-1})$ and $\iota_*\circ r_* = \text{id}\colon\pi_1(\Bbb R^n-\{0\}) \to\pi_1(\Bbb R^n-\{0\})$.

Comment: Even without any theory this is an easy result: take a loop in $\mathbb R^n-0$, retract it into $S^{n-1}$, contract it into a point and you're done.

Comment: @TedShifrin We know $r  \circ \iota = \mathrm{id}$ and so $r_* \circ \iota_* = \mathrm{id}_*$. But we only know $\iota \circ r \simeq \mathrm{id}$. So, we don't know $\iota_* \circ r_* = \mathrm{id}_*$.

Comment: @Wojowu Right. It's easy to see. But how does the corollary follow from the prop?

Comment: Ah, I don't have the book on hand, so I can't double-check what you're saying. It seems dubious, but OK. Are you telling me Lee doesn't prove earlier that if $Y$ is a strong deformation retract of $X$ then $\pi_1(X)\cong\pi_1(Y)$?

Comment: I literally just explained that. It's the proposition which says $\mathbb R^n-0$ retracts onto the sphere.

Comment: @TedShifrin No. That's Thm 7.40. It comes a few lines after.

Comment: @AlJebr: Have you already proven that $f_\ast  = g_\ast $ if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic?  Once you have that, the condition $\iota \circ r  \simeq id$ gets the result you need.

Comment: @JasonDeVito No. I see that proof in Munkres, but not in this book.

Comment: Wojowu has given a proof that doesn't invoke homotopy invariance (the strong deformation retract provides a homotopy taking a curve in $\Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ to a curve in $S^{n-1}$, where you already know that you can homotope it to a point, so all loops may be contracted). But beyond that, I do not understand your resistance to using elementary facts that you should be building in the theory anyway: the *point* of $\pi_1$ is that it is a homotopy invariant, and the proof (essentially Jason DeVito's comment that homotopic maps induce the same homomorphism) is very straightforward.

Comment: It might be worth checking the errata pages for Lee's book. Someone may have pointed this lacuna out to him ...

Comment: @JasonDeVito : you should be caregul with a statement like that : indeed the equality $f_*= g_*$ may not even make sense (that they are homotopic does not imply that they send a given basepoint to the same point, so we may have $\pi_1(Y, f(x_0))\neq \pi_1(Y, g(x_0))$. There are ways of adressing this (using the fundamental groupoid for instance), but I think you cannot state an intermediary result like this for fundamental groups : the only thing you can get is " a homotppy equivalence induces an isomorphism"

Comment: @Wojowu : I think the issue is more subtle because you have to watch out for the base point of the loop, which will in general change during the retraction onto $S^{n-1}$. Had we known $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus 0$ was contractible and wanted to prove that $S^{n-1}$ was as well, we could have proceeded that way because $S^{n-1}$ is a *strong* deformation retract and so the base point will not change. Going in the direction that is mentioned here takes more care

Comment: @MikeMiller : without fundamental groupoids, the proof is not *that* straightforward : one needs to pay attention to the base points of the fundamental groups and this can be quite tiresome (though it does become easy and straightforward with the $\Pi_1$, the fundamental groupoid)

Comment: @Max You overstate the difficulty when the desire is to show the group is zero, though you are right that the desired proof is not entirely self-contained: one further needs to know the action of basepoint-pushing is by conjugation, and then all that needs to be said is that there is only one group with a single conjugacy-class of elements.

Comment: @MikeMiller : I have to admit in the class I followed there wasn't a specific proof for the zero case; but I do remember some annoying details about basepoints having to be taken care of in the general case. In any case, that's not a proof that can be contained in a "qed square" like that haha

Comment: @Max Basepoints are no problem in the present case. If you agree that it is easy to verify that for pointed maps $f,g : (X,x_0) \to (Y,y_0)$ which  are pointed homotopic one has $f_\ast = g_\ast : \pi_1(X,x_0) \to \pi_1(Y,y_0)$, then we are done. Choose any $x_0 \in S^{n-1}$. Then $\iota$ and $r$ give pointed maps $\iota: (S^{n-1},x_0) \to (\mathbb{R}^n - \{ 0 \},x_0)$. But $\iota \circ r$ is pointed homotopic to $id : (\mathbb{R}^n - \{ 0 \},x_0) \to (\mathbb{R}^n - \{ 0 \},x_0)$ simply because $r$ is a strong deformation retraction. The fundamental grupoid and conjugation don't play a role.

Comment: @Max:  You're right - I needed more care.  I am just very used to base point preserving maps, sorry!

Comment: @PaulFrost : indeed, this works, but what the other comments proposed/ what the book seems to propose (I don't know if it does, I don't know the book) is not enough. Note that the comments to which I answered either didn't pay attention to basepoints or mentioned general results that did not pay attention to this subtlety (subtlety which goes away with groupoids, which is why I mentioned them)

Comment: @Max I don't know the book, too. If it should introduce the fundamental group without studying induced maps and the basic features at least on the pointed homotopy category, it would be somewhat strange. But perhaps that comes later in the book. And you are right, most comments didn't consider the pointed vs. unpointed issue. So perhaps we should know how "simply connected" is defined in the book ($\pi_1(X,x_0) = 0$ for some (or for all?) $x_0$, or each loop in $X$ is inessential?). But I believe it is not that important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wow. This is just an oversight. Corollary 7.38 should have been delayed until after the statement of Theorem 7.40, which says that $\pi_1$ is homotopy invariant. I've added a [correction](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ITM/).

Thanks for pointing this out.